# copy files to multiple computers using powershell

Tags: powershell-2.0

I need to copy files to multiple computers from my computer with following specifications.

1. I need to provide username
2. I need to provide password also
3. while running it should not prompt again for password *important*

I used the following code but it asks for the password multiple times.

```
 read-host -assecurestring | convertfrom-securestring | out-file e:\SSS\pass.txt
 $password=get-content e:\SSS\pass.txt | convertto-securestring 
 $credential=new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist KS\KS012\Administrator, $password
```

Answer (score 0):

Script below should prompt for credentials and then prompt to ask for location of txt file which has line seperated list of PC's you want to deploy to. Then it will ask for the location of the file you want to copy and then ask for the destination with a preformated UNC c$ formatting.

You can adjust this to set the list of PCs, location of file to copy and desitnation to hardcoded.

```
Get-Credential domain\usermname
$PC = Read-Host "Location of PC List"
$FileLocation = Read-Host "Enter File Location"
$FileDestination = Read-Host "Enter File Destination"
Get-Content $PC | foreach {Copy-Item $FileLocation -Destination \\$_\c$\$FileDestination}
```

:)